# How to override the Buddypress bp-members folder's file?

Tags: plugins, buddypress

Can I override the Buddypress file of this location **/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-members** like **/wp-content/plugin/buddypress/bp-templates/bp-legacy**

If yes, How can we do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No.  You can only override template files.